# What is the correct use of commas when using the word "attached"

Tags: punctuation, commas, formality

What is the correct comma use in the following sentence?

Per our earlier conversation, attached, please find the document.

Comment: That sounds to me as if the conversation is attached. Try something like "As promised/discussed in our earlier conversation, the requested document is attached." "Per" is very old-fashioned business-speak and is best avoided.

Comment: Additionally, this type of simple question is better asked on our sister site [ell.se].

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it better suited to [ell.se]

Comment: I suggest you elide the words "please find," as they simply are not necessary--unless of course you've hidden the attachment and the recipient has to hunt for it.  Better:  "I've attached the document we talked about earlier."  Simple.

Answer (score 1):

As per our earlier conversation, please find the document attached. (To that effect)

Comment: What does that first *As* there add?  I think it read better with out it.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is not incorrect. Personally, I would probably use parentheses instead of commas—especially in an email, which is what I assume this is.

Answer (score 0):

> Per our earlier conversation, attached, please find the document.

As it is written, this sentence means that you have provided an attachment containing the earlier conversation, and are reminding the addressee that the result of that conversation was that they need to go find a document somewhere.  The "parenthetical" comments around *attached* naturally associate it with the initial phrase, making it into a description of "the earlier conversation".  The second phrase then becomes a request for action instead of a direction to a particular location.

> Per our earlier conversation, attached please find the document.

The removal of the comma after *attached* changes the meaning significantly:  now it means that as a result of the earlier conversation, you have attached a document to this message and the addressee is politely requested to open and read it.

Generally I would expect that the second meaning is the one most commonly intended.